# 8th positive odd integer that is an ODD Catalan number?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recursion, catalan-numbers

The $n^{\text{th}}$ Catalan number is given by the formula $C_n = \frac 1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$.

It also satisfies the recurence \begin{align*}C_n &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-1-k}\\ &= C_0C_{n-1}+C_1C_{n-2}+C_2C_{n-3}+\cdots+C_{n-1}C_0\end{align*} for all n greater than or equal to 1.

What is the eighth positive integer n for which $C_n$ is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By considering the greatest power of two that divides $(2n)!$ against the maximum power of two that divides $n!(n+1)!$, we have that $C_n$ is always even unless $n=2^k-1$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

The OEIS has a list of odd Catalan Numbers, [A038003](http://oeis.org/A038003). The 8th odd Catalan number is 73 digits long. A quick check with Wolfram Alpha tells me that this number is $C_{127}$

In general, it appears that $C_x$ is odd when $x=2^n-1$ for some natural number $n$, and even otherwise.

Comment: @Kmarts: The 8th Catalan number from OEIS is: 11311095732253345760960290897769189975961199415637572612957718759342193629 , but when checking 2^{127}-1 it doesn't match it. Are they supposed to match?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the $8$th odd Catalan number is the $2^8-1=127$th Catalan number (or $C_{127}$). The $9$th odd Catalan number would be the $255$th Catalan number, and so on.

Comment: I entered in 127 and it was incorrect. However, I did notice that  2^8-1 = 255, not 127.

Comment: EDIT: Yep, it's 255

Comment: @MathyPerson Oops, yeah, that was an oversight on my part. You did say the eighth *positive* integer, but the typical sequence of Catalan numbers (like the one on OEIS) starts at zero, $C_0=1$. So, the eighth odd Catalan number is $C_{127}$, but the eighth $n\in\Bbb{Z}^+$ such that $C_{n}$ is odd is $n=255$.